# PENTAHO-CONNECTION VARIABLES

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

How can i pass database connection details as parameter/variable, using set variables.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the below steps and official documents:

- [To set a variable using Spoon](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.0/Products/Data_Integration/Data_Integration_Perspective/050/020/000/010/010#Set_Kettle_Variables_in_Spoon):

  > In Spoon, select Edit > Edit the kettle.properties file.
  >   In the Kettle Properties window, modify the variable value. 
  >   If you want to add a variable, complete these steps.
  >   Right-click on a line number, then select Insert before this row or Insert after this row. 
  >   Enter the variable name and value.
  >   If you want to reposition the variable, right-click on the row number again, then select Move Up or Move Down.
  >   Click the OK button.

Add your database properties using the above step.

- [To Access the variable in your transformation or jobs:](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Data_Integration_Perspective/Run_Modifiers/Variables)

> The Get Variable and Get Session Variables steps can explicitly retrieve a value from a variable.
>       ${VARIABLE}
>       %%VARIABLE%%